# tikzpicture, feynman, equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, feynman

How can I put the expression beginning from the center of this diagram?
the expression is a bit higher, I want it at a lower and close-center position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a1.base)]
\large
\begin{feynman}[inline=(a1.base)]
   \vertex (a1) {\(d\)};
    \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
    \vertex[right=2cm of a2] (a3) {\(s\)};
    \vertex[below=4em of a1] (b1) {\(\overline s\)};
        \vertex[right=2cm of b1] (b2);
    \vertex[right=2cm of b2] (b3) {\(\overline d\)};
    
     \diagram* {
      {[edges=fermion]
        (a1) -- (a2) -- (a3) 
      },
     {[edges= anti fermion]
        (b1) -- (b2) -- (b3)
      },
      (a2) -- [dashed, edge label=\(Q_i\)] (b2),
      };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\equiv <Q_i>(\alpha_s^0)=Q_i,\\\quad \text{for}\quad Q_i=Q_1,Q_2,E_1,E_2 .
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. I will suggest \langle and \rangle instead of < and >.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you after. Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a1.base)]
\large
\begin{feynman}[inline=(a1.base)]
   \vertex (a1) {\(d\)};
    \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
    \vertex[right=2cm of a2] (a3) {\(s\)};
    \vertex[below=4em of a1] (b1) {\(\overline s\)};
        \vertex[right=2cm of b1] (b2);
    \vertex[right=2cm of b2] (b3) {\(\overline d\)};
    
     \diagram* {
      {[edges=fermion]
        (a1) -- (a2) -- (a3) 
      },
     {[edges= anti fermion]
        (b1) -- (b2) -- (b3)
      },
      (a2) -- [dashed, edge label=\(Q_i\)] (b2),
      };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\equiv <Q_i>(\alpha_s^0)=Q_i,\\\quad \text{for}\quad Q_i=Q_1,Q_2,E_1,E_2 .
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you meant the equation into the center?
You could make it a simple node ike this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a1.base)]         
            \node at (7,-1) {\( \begin{split}\equiv <Q_i>(\alpha_s^0)=Q_i,\\\quad \text{for}\quad Q_i=Q_1,Q_2,E_1,E_2 \end{split} \)};
            \large
            \begin{feynman}[inline=(a1.base)]
                \vertex (a1) {\(d\)};
                \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
                \vertex[right=2cm of a2] (a3) {\(s\)};
                \vertex[below=4em of a1] (b1) {\(\overline s\)};
                \vertex[right=2cm of b1] (b2);
                \vertex[right=2cm of b2] (b3) {\(\overline d\)};                
                \diagram* {
                    {[edges=fermion]
                        (a1) -- (a2) -- (a3) 
                    },
                    {[edges= anti fermion]
                        (b1) -- (b2) -- (b3)
                    },
                    (a2) -- [dashed, edge label=\(Q_i\)] (b2),              
                };
            \end{feynman}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        %\equiv <Q_i>(\alpha_s^0)=Q_i,\\\quad \text{for}\quad Q_i=Q_1,Q_2,E_1,E_2 .
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Now the layout of the diagram and equation looks better!